# "NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined" even though redirect is imported

Tags: python, flask

I have this simple Flask 1.1.x app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
    
@app.route('/donate', methods=['GET'])
def donate():
    return render_template("donate.html")

@app.route('/donations', methods=['GET'])
def donations():
    return redirect(url_for('donate'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I'm developing on a local server. When I attempt to access `/donations` in a browser, I get an Internal Server Error and the local server reports this error:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /donations [GET]
<trimmed>
    return redirect(url_for('donate'))
NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined
```

I don't understand why it's reporting `redirect` as undefined, since I am importing it and I'm calling it the same way the [Flack Quickstart Guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) does.

Comment: Your code is correct. My guess is, that there is somehow a bad char or a strange formating. Try to copy your code from the question to a new file and run it.

Comment: This inexplicably started working so I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you replace `return redirect(url_for('donate'))` with `return redirect('/donate')` ?